# Detecting onload event in IE for iFrame which has PDF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I see that this question has been asked many times here. Some of the solutions partially work. This is the scenario. I need to load an iframe which has a pdf using `<embed>`. There are chances the PDF is not found and I will be showing error page within iFrame.

Once the iframe is loaded, I look for `<embed>` tag using

`$('#iframe').contents().find('embed')`

I tried using `$('#iframe').load()`. This works in Firefox, Chrome but not IE.

Also tried using `$('#iframe').ready()`. This works in IE, however,

`$('#iframe').contents().find('embed')` doesn't work.

Can someone please help out ?

**EDIT :**  IE Version : 7 or 8. Same origin policy is respected.

Comment: You might want to verify: Are your parent and iframe using the same document.domain? IE is very sensitive to security in regard to iframes and cross domain scripting...

Comment: When I switch my browser mode to IE7 or IE8 it still works with my test setup. Jquery version?

Comment: I tried using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js and my small test setup still works. I don't know if this is because I'm looking at this locally. Have you tried this simple test setup on your site to see if the problem is actually bound to this specifically?

Comment: @IvanL : Locally it works. However, when run on server, IE7 is giving 'Object required' or 'No such interface found' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#iframe').load` or `<iframe onload="">` doesn't work. Looks like in IE iframe contents for PDF cannot be accessed. So to track iFrame load, following code can be used.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    try {
            var s = window.frames[ "iframeName" ].document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            if(s.indexOf('My error message') > 0) {
                alert('Error');
            } else {
                alert('PDF');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            if($.trim(err.message) != 'Access is denied.') {
                alert('PDF');
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
});
```

So in case a error message 'My error message' is found then it is the custom-designed-error page which has the message, else it is the PDF.

The above solution is for IE7 & IE8. For the rest of the browsers, following can be checked 
`$('#iframe').contents().find('embed').attr('src')`

Not a straight forward solution. But works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jquery and IE are you using? I made a small test setup like follows and it works just fine...

**Main HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('iframe').ready(function(){
                var tag = $('#iframe').contents().find('embed');
                alert(tag.attr('src'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="pdf.html">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Iframe HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <embed src="mypdf.pdf"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tested on Windows 7, IE9.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If embed is forcefully written, it works. Instead of pdf.html, in case a Servlet prints the PDF in response stream, the IE will introduce embed within iFrame. In this case, embed cannot be accessed.

Comment: I see, the PDF was being printed directly without embed and IE introduced a sort of ghost embed to contain the PDF which you cannot access. Glad I could help you find the source of the problem and resolve it.

Comment: Sorry but the issue isn't resolved. I still need to verify if iFrame contains a PDF. `$('#iframe').contents().find('embed')` is not working in IE :( It is like `<iframe src="link-to-get-pdf-inline"></iframe>` So IE adds embed and wont allow us to access it

Comment: Hmn then I misunderstood your last message. So the problem now is that when your servlet prints the PDF you have a problem and when you write an embed tag it works? Have you tried having the servlet write out an embed instead of only the PDF? I fear you'll need to post some of the code that creates your page so we can look for the reason it's not working.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer did help me. So I have added +1 for your answer. Looks like I resolved it. Will post the answer soon.